# how to find a:visited styles in firebug/FF Dev Tools

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm fairly new to coding so I apologise in advance.

I have a css problem... with visited links in that they are not sticking to the style I have created for them once visited:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #1997E0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

What techniques can I use to investigate what is overriding the new rules I have set in my Wordpress child theme? I don't seem to be able to find what is causing the issue using FF Dev Tools or Firebug.

The site is http://www.motonetblog.co.uk if anyone cares to look.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the links in the sidebar, there is this rule which overrides the `a:visited` style:

```
.widget-area .widget a, .widget-area .widget a:visited {
  color: #1997E0;
}
```

Comment: No it's only happening to links in the posts themselves (such as continue reading or inline href strings). The post titles behave as expected. Thanks

Comment: I have figured it out now.

The posts also have overriding rules so I created  
     .entry-content a:link, .entry-content a:visited {
        color: #1997E0;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

This worked for me. Thanks so much